# Storing two way relational data in Redis

Tags: nosql, redis

Over the last few days I've been working on a very simple web service for myself (and a few others) that allows me to keep track of books that I've read and when I've read them. Whilst storing users and books (titles + authors + maybe more data in the future) is relatively simple because they can just be stored as hashes with keys `user:username` and `book:uniqueID` respectively storing which users read which books and when is proving to be a bit more challenge.

My original plan was to have a sorted set for a user (`user:username:readbooks`) that used the timestamp as a score (for when the user read the book) and each book's unique ID as the value. The problem with this approach is that I can't store that a user has read a book twice (as you can't have duplicate values in a set). It also means that in order to track readers of a book I have to add them to a second set `readersof:bookID`.

My current approach that is rather than directly storing book IDs in the set `user:username:readbooks`to instead store a value in the form `uniqueReadingEventId.bookId`, however the problem with this is that if I delete a book (rather than the unique reading event) I have to iterate through every user in the set `readersof:bookID`, iterate through every value in `user:username:readbooks` and deleting values that match `x.bookId`, which seems a little inefficient. Furthermore, I may want to find users that have read two or more books in common.

My question is therefore two fold: is there a simpler way to structure my data in Redis or is my data better structured to a different NoSQL system? I would really like to continue working with Redis because I like its API, however because it is a personal project it doesn't really matter what I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you need really high throughput here for some reason, it doesn't sound like Redis is the right choice. It sounds like you want to store a lot of document level information, and neither high-throughput nor data structures are a huge concern for you. To me that screams for just using SQL. Your data is very schematic-- and from what you've said, there's really no reason SQL wouldn't best and most simply fit your use case. If you're married to the idea of using NoSQL, one of the more general use-case databases like Mongo would also serve well.

Redis as a persistent database is specialized for cases where you need high throughput, data structures are useful, and you don't mind paying the extra cost of keeping everything in memory instead of much less expensive HD space. There are lots of scenarios where Redis fits perfectly, but yours isn't one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This was mostly done as an experiment with NoSQL systems (my primary experience in databases previously was MySQL and SQLite), and Redis initially seemed like a good solution but perhaps Mongo will be a better solution. Please could you explain the difference between 'schematic data' and 'structured data'?

Comment: By data structures I just mean the typical data structures in computer science theory as implemented in Redis: hashes, lists, sets, etc... Some of these have nice properties you want to make use of (like if you know you just need a hash and will never need to sort, etc...), which is easy to do and understand in Redis and not something you have access to in other databases.

By schematic data, I mean data that fits a strict, predefined schema. This is in contrast to data where different documents in a single table have different attributes. Your data is very schematic.